# Remotely playing guitar with more than two persons at the same time

Tags: guitar, practice

Due to the COVID19, me and my friends started gathering online in an online video chat tool to play guitar.

We managed to play, but terribly...

What's the technique that can be used in this case to make it work?

Comment: Although obviously asked for a different reason, I’m pretty sure this is a dupe and that we’ve been asked about remote rehearsing before.

Comment: Here’s a question and answers that might help: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/10576/9198

Comment: If you use our search function you might find other posts with advice.

Comment: No problem. Stay safe. And I hope you find a good solution for playing music!

Comment: I'm considering phone conferences and Jamulus. Still looking to see how that plays out.